# Design pattern to inherit derived members from non-modifiable base classes?

Tags: c#, inheritance, design-patterns

I have the following chicken/egg inheritance problem:

Here, base classes I can derive from, but they're on a framework, thus, I can't modify them:

```
class Editor
{

}

class ScriptedImporterEditor : Editor
{
}
```

Here, are classes in my project:

An editor with a preview, this works as expected, `Cylinder` and `Torus` have `DrawPreview`:

```
class EditorWithPreview : Editor
{
    public void DrawPreview(){}
}
   
class Cylinder : EditorWithPreview
{
    // DrawPreview is available
}

class Torus : EditorWithPreview
{
    // DrawPreview is available
}
```

But now I need a scripted importer editor that can also preview:

```
class ScriptedImporterEditorWithPreview : ScriptedImporterEditor
{
    // cannot inherit EditorWithPreview as it's not a ScriptedImporterEditor
}

class Cube : ScriptedImporterEditorWithPreview 
{
    // unable to use DrawPreview
}

class Sphere : ScriptedImporterEditorWithPreview 
{
    // unable to use DrawPreview
}
```

So basically,

- I can't change neither `Editor` nor `ScriptedImporterEditor` as I don't own them
- I therefore cannot import the logic of `EditorWithPreview` to `ScriptedImporterEditor`
- `Cube` and `Sphere` can't inherit and use `DrawPreview`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following may help.

```
class ScriptedImporterEditorWithPreview : ScriptedImporterEditor
{
    private EditorWithPreview editorWithPreview = null;
    public ScriptedImporterEditorWithPreview(EditorWithPreview editorWithPreview)
    {
         this.editorWithPreview = editorWithPreview;
    }
    public virtual void DrawPreview()  // based on need it is virtual or non-virtual
    {
         this.editorWithPreview.DrawPreview();
    }
}

class Cube : ScriptedImporterEditorWithPreview 
{
    
}

class Sphere : ScriptedImporterEditorWithPreview 
{
    
}
```

Comment: It ended up substiantially different because of XYZ but indeed led me to the solution. 